# Does BootCamp cause OS X shutdown to be slow?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, shutdown

Does having a BootCamp partition somehow make OS X shutdown slow?

Shutting down OS X on my somewhat old (2009) MacBook Pro used to take five seconds or less. But lately I've both installed an SSD and started using BootCamp, and now shutting down OS X -- even when no apps are running and I don't choose to restart apps next time -- takes 23 seconds.

My Windows 8.1 and OS X start up are very quickly, and Windows 8.1 shuts down within a few seconds too.

It's unfortunate that I installed the SSD and BootCamp so close together, because if one of those is the reason, it's hard to tell which one it might be. But I really doubt an SSD would make it *slower*. Other possibilities are OS X updates (it was already behaving this way before I installed 10.9.3, so that particular update isn't the culprit), or some background service I might have running (e.g. BetterTouchTool, KeyRemap4MacBook, ShiftIt, VirtualBox, Dropbox, Spotify, ssh-agent; but I was running those things for a long time before this slowdown started).

I have tried repairing permissions, and using the `defaults` commands at [What is the reason for the slow shutdown?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116237/what-is-the-reason-for-the-slow-shutdown), with no success. (That page asks a more general version of the question I'm asking here.)

Here is all that was in my console log since I ran the `defaults` commands until the next startup; I don't see anything in it that suggests a reason for the slow shutdown:

```
5/18/14 6:32:38.350 PM login[815]: DEAD_PROCESS: 815 ttys000
5/18/14 6:32:48.868 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280]: (com.apple.PackageKit.InstallStatus) Throttling respawn: Will start in 7 seconds
5/18/14 6:32:48.907 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.907 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.907 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.907 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.907 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.908 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.908 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.908 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.908 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.908 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.908 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.909 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.910 PM WindowServer[130]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 53003
5/18/14 6:32:48.933 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ShareKitHelper[402]) Exited: Killed: 9
5/18/14 6:32:48.933 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.internetaccounts[404]) Exited: Killed: 9
5/18/14 6:32:48.945 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280]: (com.hp.devicemonitor[309]) Exited: Killed: 9
5/18/14 6:32:49.023 PM UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [UserAgentDied:142] User Agent @port=68875 Died
5/18/14 6:32:49.026 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280]: (com.apple.iTunesHelper.50368[347]) Exited with code: 1
5/18/14 6:32:49.028 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280]: (com.apple.gamed[356]) Exited: Killed: 9
5/18/14 6:32:49.028 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280]: ([0x0-0x29029].com.apple.AppleSpell[472]) Exited: Killed: 9
5/18/14 6:32:49.028 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280]: (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua[284]) Exited: Killed: 9
5/18/14 6:32:49.111 PM accountsd[362]: /SourceCache/Accounts/Accounts-336.9/ACDAuthenticationPluginManager.m - -[ACDAuthenticationPluginManager credentialForAccount:client:handler:] - 230 - The authentication plugin for account "echristopherson@gmail.com" (36AE7882-C0B5-43FC-B2F5-D44F5BB4F987) could not be found!
5/18/14 6:32:49.111 PM accountsd[362]: /SourceCache/Accounts/Accounts-336.9/ACDAccountStore.m - __62-[ACDAccountStore credentialForAccountWithIdentifier:handler:]_block_invoke389 - 857 - No plugin provides credentials for account echristopherson@gmail.com. Falling back to legacy behavior.
5/18/14 6:32:49.128 PM sessionlogoutd[1028]: sessionlogoutd Launched
5/18/14 6:32:49.143 PM sessionlogoutd[1028]: DEAD_PROCESS: 68 console
5/18/14 6:32:49.000 PM kernel[0]: Kext loading now disabled.
5/18/14 6:32:49.000 PM kernel[0]: Kext unloading now disabled.
5/18/14 6:32:49.000 PM kernel[0]: Kext autounloading now disabled.
5/18/14 6:32:49.000 PM kernel[0]: Kernel requests now disabled.
5/18/14 6:32:49.203 PM shutdown[1029]: halt by _cvmsroot: 
5/18/14 6:32:49.204 PM shutdown[1029]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1400455969 203505
5/18/14 6:32:49.289 PM CalendarAgent[325]: xpc __securityd_create_connection_block_invoke got event: Connection interrupted
5/18/14 6:32:49.301 PM identityservicesd[321]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
5/18/14 6:32:49.302 PM imagent[320]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
5/18/14 6:32:49.302 PM identityservicesd[321]: xpc __securityd_create_connection_block_invoke got event: Connection interrupted
5/18/14 6:32:49.303 PM identityservicesd[321]: Quit - shutting down daemon
5/18/14 6:32:49.304 PM imagent[320]: Quit - shutting down daemon
5/18/14 6:32:49.310 PM distnoted[285]: Interruption - exiting now.
5/18/14 6:32:49.310 PM distnoted[285]: Interruption - exiting now.
5/18/14 6:32:49.310 PM distnoted[285]: Interruption - exiting now.
5/18/14 6:32:49.310 PM distnoted[285]: Interruption - exiting now.
5/18/14 6:33:29.000 PM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1400456009 0
```

Comment: No idea if this will work, but it did for me (on 10.8.5); look for link to DMG for little script to run: http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/292760-intermittent-shutdown-problem-on-mavericks/

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That script seems to be an updated version of the `defaults` commands I posted. I'm still experimenting, but strangely, it seems like running the script makes the *very next* shutdown fast, but subsequent ones are slow again. Also I have just noticed Chrome sometimes takes quite a while to stop, which may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some software running or hardware plugged into your mac that is deliberately delaying the shutdown process for some reason.

It's hard to know what it is, except to start randomly uninstalling and/or unplugging stuff. In general, a clean install of OS X with no third party hardware plugged in will shut down in a split second, but once you install a bunch of stuff it starts to take longer and longer.

You could narrow it down by testing how long it takes to shut down while at the login screen, or by logging in as a different user (create a new blank user account just to test it) and shut down from there. If it's faster, then it is probably something in your login items that slows things down.

Or, it could be a kernel extension, system daemon (apache/mysql causes slow shut downs on my mac), mouse driver, printer driver, etc that is causing the slow down. In those cases it won't matter if you are logged in or logged out when you shut down.

In general though, you're not looking for a single problem. There are probably 20 or 30 things slowing down your shutdown process. From the look of the log, you sent, it's sending a shutdown message to a bunch of stuff in a single second, then taking about 40 seconds for all of them to actually close. It does not do them one at a time, it does all of them simultaneously.

You might want to start by looking into that log message `"No plugin provides credentials for account e.....n@gmail.com."` - that suggests something on your mac is logging into a remote server during the shutdown process, and probably delaying the shutdown until it gets a response.

As for your main question about bootcamp... No. It's highly improbable that Bootcamp causes any performance impact at all, unless you start running very low on disk space (some disks, especially SSD drives, tend to run slower if they are over 90% full).

Comment: Hmm. Yes, if I shut down with a dummy user logged in, or from the login window, it is quick. I've just spent an hour or so trying different things like disabling things in my own LaunchAgents/LaunchDaemons and Login Items, and also in the systemwide directories just in case, but haven't had any real luck with it. I thought I had something when I made shutdown slow with my dummy account logged in, by setting key shortcuts for changing input methods, thus causing TISwitcher to run, but taking out those shortcuts in my main user didn't help there.

Comment: I can't figure out the credentials message, either. It looks like lots of people have that in their logs, but I haven't found anything about what app or service it belongs to. I went ahead and remove my Apple ID from the iCloud settings (since I don't use iCloud anyway), but I still get that same message in the logs.

Comment: @echristopherson try searching your keychain for the email address listed, there might be a password entry for it. Edit the keychain entry and see what apps are listed under Access Control.

Comment: I now have fast shutdowns at least sometimes, and I didn't get rid of BootCamp, so you must be right. (Thought it was a long shot to begin with.) I went through quite a few things, like cleaning user and system caches with OnyX; disabling and reenabling swap (this was recommended somewhere, but I don't see how it would work); and running the `defaults` commands. Finally it *seems* that booting in Safe Boot and then rebooting normally was what fixed it. I still haven't identified any significant differences in processes running under my different users.

Comment: @echristopherson it might also be something in ~/Library that is causing the slow shutdowns. Also when testing it, make sure your mac isn't still booting up when you do a shutdown... it might do a bunch of stuff in the background for a few minutes after booting (eg: check for expired SSL certificates, check for software update, update safari's list of known-malware infested domain names).